# Error al firmar con algoritmos SHA-256 o superior con iTextSharp

Tags: c#, algoritmos, itextsharp, sha256

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo para firmar documentos PDF con los certificados listados en el almacen de windows (Instalados, Token, Smart Card) utilizando iTextSharp, mi problema se da al utilizar los algoritmos de firma (ya que este puede ser configurable), al momento de utilizar un algoritmo distinto a SHA-1 me muestra el error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Algoritmo
>   especificado no es válido.

El error se da en el metodo **Sign(byte[] message)** de la clase **X509Certificate2Signature**, este es el fragmento de codigo donde ocurre el error:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
return rsa.SignData(message, hashAlgorithm);
```

He leído que debo exportar el certificado y especificar el uso del CSP de windows, pero al utilizar certificados en Token esto no es viable.

Espero me apoyen, Gracias.

Comment: Este enlace puede ayudarte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7433202/2844593

Comment: Gracias, lo estoy revisando.